# Is there an better alternative to Condition statement to stop Logic App?

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, azure-logic-apps

I currently have a Logic App that has an empty false path since the Logic App. The only reason I use a condition is because the LogicApp should stop when the condition is false. Is there a better alternative to stop a Logic App when a certain condition/statement is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Terminate action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#terminate-action):

> This action stops the run for a workflow instance, cancels any actions in progress, skips any remaining actions, and returns the specified status. For example, you can use the Terminate action when your logic app must exit completely from an error state. This action doesn't affect already completed actions and can't appear inside Foreach and Until loops, including sequential loops.

You can refer to my logic app:

[image]

This is my test result, it seems there is no problem：

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Terminate in the false should be added indeed.
Is it really a best practice to use the Conditional Statement in these kind of scenarios? I was thinking about perhaps an 'if-statement', but it will lower the readability quality in the actions.

Comment: If you pursue readability, then this solution is possible. If the `if statement` can reduce an action, the cost will be reduced accordingly. So the specific solution you choose depends on you.